# How do I call concat_idents inside a recursive macro expansion?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a macro to expand a set of names and define fields for a struct:

```
macro_rules! expand {
  ($($name:ident),*) => {
     pub struct Test {
       $(
          concat_idents!(var_, $name) : Vec<$name>
        ),*
     }
  }
}
//fails
expand!(a,b,c);
```

This fails as the compiler does not recognize `concat_idents!` as a macro. How am I supposed to work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not at present possible to do this in any way. Substitutions (`$foo`) are fine there, but not macro calls.

Comment: This response is outdated, its perfectly legal to do macro calls inside macro differentiation.  I'm using version1.24.0-nightly.

Comment: @LukeDupin: no; the answer is still correct, nothing has changed: the parser does not accept macros in field name position. To remove `macro_rules!` from the equation, try `struct Test { concat_idents!(var_, a): u8 }`: It fails to parse.